# CSS: keep list-style on floated li elements

Tags: css

Here is an example:

```
<ul>
    <li>list</li>
    <li style="float:left;">list</li>
    <li style="float:left;">list</li>
    <li style="float:left;">list</li>
    <li style="float:left;">list</li>
</ul>
```

How to keep list-style on the rest li elements while keeping float?

Thanks ;)

Comment: list elements keep their default styles even when floating, I don't really understand what you want.

Comment: Yes, list elements generally keep their styles even when set to float. Is it possible that the list bullet is being covered up? Try adding more of a left margin to your `li`s and see if they reappear. Also, which browser are you using? Different browsers style list items in different ways, which could be causing your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having played a bit more, are you using IE? Also, are you specifying a DOCTYPE, to avoid quirks mode? There was some odd behaviour in IE6 with floats and list item bullets that may be being carried forward in quirks.

Looks to me like Internet Explorer clobbers the list style type when floating. Adding it back in works fine. See http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/VZC7F/5/ for your markup with some extra CSS styling that makes it work. That should be cross-browser safe, as far as I can see.

Complete example using inline styles:

```
<ul>     
  <li>list</li>
  <li style="float:left; margin-left: 20px; list-style-type: square;">list</li>     
  <li style="float:left; margin-left: 20px; list-style-type: square;">list</li>     
  <li style="float:left; margin-left: 20px; list-style-type: square;">list</li>     
  <li style="float:left; margin-left: 20px; list-style-type: square;">list</li> 
</ul>
```

...though of course it'll be more efficient to use a non-inline style/stylesheet as in my jsFiddle example.

My example works in IE8. It looks like [the bullets might have disappeard in a more fundamental way in earlier version of IE](http://venutip.com/content/disappearing-bullets-ie); that article explains the behaviour and gives a way of recreating them, albeit with a bit of an annoying workaround (it basically recreates the missing bullets with a background-image.)

Comment: Thanks mate. Your solution with reassigning list-style-type works. Don't care about IE7 anymore. :D

Comment: Damn why the... it's working in jsfiddle, but doesn't on my page... Can't display page, it's on local server. Why it would not work?

Comment: Just a moment. I'll host images.

Comment: @Beck Have you got a valid DOCTYPE at the top of your local page? It might be rendering in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) if not, which would probably cause a regression to the earlier IE6/7 behaviour.

Comment: God damn it. Thanks mate. I'm soooo dumb. Forgot to apply doctype at all :D Haven't sleep well last few days... Sorry everyone. Matt please edit your post. Add there a note about the proper Doctype at the top with a bold text. Thank you ;)

Comment: @Beck No worries; it's easy to forget, especially when you're knocking stuff together quickly...

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li>list</li>
    <li style="float:left; clear: left;">list</li>
    <li style="float:left; clear: left;">list</li>
    <li style="float:left; clear: left;">list</li>
    <li style="float:left; clear: left;">list</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: depends what you are trying to do, I don't think I completely understand what is desired here. What is meant exactly by list-style? Should the UL be floated instead of the elements? etc..?

Comment: I need to keep list-style squares. They dissapear when li is floated. Billy Moon in your example they dissapear except first element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SuperPhil/VZC7F/1/) of what I could come up with. They are all floating left except the first one and maintain the squares.